# Bookmark/favourites within the site itself

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Would it be possible to have a favourites/bookmark within the site itself?

It could be something which could be in user's profile so they have access to it without being dependent on the browser bookmark feature.

This would be good so I could be anywhere, I don't need even to sign in, just come to the site, come to my profile (just need to remember my username) and I can access any of the questions I have favoured/bookmarked for anytime consumption.

Comment: Isn't that already implemented? Click on the star below the two voting arrows to add the question as a favourite. Or are you looking for something different?

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for, I suggest the tags [meta-tag:faq-proposed] and [meta-tag:support].

Answer (score 1):

This feature already exists! You have the option of marking questions as [favourites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585). To do this, simply click the star below the voting buttons of a question as shown in the image below:

[image: Favourite question star] [image: Unmarked star] [image: This question is nobody’s favourite]

In the left-most picture, the star is yellow because I starred that question for myself as a favourite. I can also see that 14 other users starred that question. The middle image shows a question favourited by one other user (but not me) and the one on the right wasn’t favourited by anybody.

These favourite questions show up in your profile under the *favorites* tab:

[image: Favourite tab in the profile]

Again you can see that fourteen other people favourited that first question which you saw before. It also includes all other questions I ever favourited. If something happened to one of those that renders it active in any way, there is a small blue number next to *favorites* which signifies how many active favourites there are; these are then highlighted yellow in the tab. This helps you keep track of what changed within your favourites.

> There is no limit to the number of favorites you pick. Furthermore, you can retract a favorite at any time by just clicking on the star. There is no limit to the number of times you can retract or reinstate a question as your favorite. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585))

Of course, while there is no limit you have to decide for yourself when this feature loses its usefulness.